# How can I be sure that my charities do NOT give aid in the form of money to terrorist organizations or any group that harbors weapons in any form?

Tags: charity

I would never have thought of asking this question. The thought never even crossed my mind until I saw an article about this topic. I donate to charities myself and just want to make sure the charities I use do not give cash to terrorists.

As far as I know they provide food and services not cash. I don't think this is an issue for my donations but would not mind getting feedback.

Here is the link:https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/hamas-cash-to-crypto-global-finance-maze-israels-sights-2023-10-16/

Comment: Define "charity" and specify a country.  It is highly, highly unlikely that contributions to a 501(c)(3) organization in the US would find its way to a terrorist organization.  If you are giving to a group in, say, Jordan that isn't a registered charity but says it has charitable aims, the risk is much higher.

Comment: @Jordan Cave Thank you. You have answered my question. I was concerned about my  specific charities which are U.S. based. It makes sense that the article was referring to charities not in the U.S. I did not stop to think of that. Other than deleting the question I don't know how to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JustinCave [It happens](https://www.justice.gov/archive/opa/pr/2008/January/08_nsd_029.html)

Comment: He said "highly unlikely" not never. Anything is possible, but some research and common sense goes a long way.

Comment: You may want to consider rewording the title of your question.  I noticed it had a downvote, perhaps because someone thought you wanted to support terrorism, which clearly you do *not*.

Comment: Worth pointing out that one man's terrorist may be another man's freedom fighter. If you don't trust the charities to make the same evaluations you do, you're going to have to dig into specific cases. Or focus on charities that provide non-cash assistance. (Which reminds me, I should increase my donation to MSF this year.)

Comment: @keshlam MSF has been mentioned [here](https://www.ngo-monitor.org/reports/ngos-bolster-hamas-human-shields-strategy-and-cynical-manipulation-of-humanitarian-evacuation/) as one of the NGOs advocating for civilians to **stay** in the war zone (as ironic as it may sound).

Comment: @-End Anti Sementic Hate. I didn't think of that ...thank you for pointing it out. I will have to fix that in no uncertain terms. The way i edited it should make the cheese a little more binding...take a look ...let me know if I can improve it. :)

Comment: @keshlam... Doctors without borders is one of my favorites. Thank you for giving.

Comment: @littleadv...Thank you for interesting information. I think MSF was saying that because sometime when you move you can go to a worse spot unless there is clear passage and logistics to go with it. It make sense.

Comment: @Sedumjoy I think in this case MSF was issuing a vanilla statement required by the local authorities (aka Hamas, which is the entity governing Gaza). Charities cannot operate there without at least some concessions to the terrorists, it's just the way life is. I generally prefer donating to charities helping Palestinians but operating in Israel (for example funding medical treatment for Palestinians in the Israeli hospitals), as the charities operating in the areas controlled by Palestinians (especially Gaza) are susceptible to pressure and corruption of the local government.

Comment: @littleadv Interesting thank you... I give to both as long as they are good charites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "charity" and specify a country.

If you are in the United States giving money to a registered 501(c)(3) charitable organization, it is highly, highly unlikely that your contributions would flow to a terrorist organization.  Money laundering does happen but it is incredibly rare.  Assuming the charity has existed for a few years, any number of charity watchdogs should be able to report on the charity's financial statements to evaluate whether there is anything dodgy.

If you are in a country in the Middle East giving to a non-registered organization that claims it has charitable goals, it is much more plausible that you're giving to an organization that is a front for terrorists.

If you don't limit yourself to cash assistance, then things get stickier.  It is always possible that terrorist groups that control territory will repurpose legitimate charitable infrastructure.  For example, Hamas used a lot of the water pipes that charitable organizations installed to build rocket launchers.  The charities couldn't control what happened to the pipes they installed once they left.

Answer (score 1):

Charities obviously are not intended to give money to terrorists directly.

But, many charities are being used (either intentionally or not, from charity's employees' and donors' perspectives) by the terrorists.

Think of UNRWA for example, a UN agency and a relatively reputable charity for the Palestinians. Their facilities have been used numerously by Hamas to stockpile weapons, fire at the Israeli civilian populations, and all that even when children were present. See [the UN report on this](https://unwatch.org/un-admits-palestinians-fired-rockets-unrwa-schools/) from one of the previous rounds of violence in the area. Obviously, the UN didn't build its schools to be used for launching missiles into the neighboring countries. But what can they do when Hamas comes and does that? Nothing.

In addition, keep in mind that the local government is a theocratic dictatorship, there's no freedom of press, no freedom of expression, no protection to whistleblowers, and [very violent punishments](https://www.euractiv.com/section/global-europe/news/hamas-executes-palestinians-for-collaboration-with-israel/) for what may be considered as "cooperating with the occupation" (and that can include letting the Israelis and the world know when the charities are misused and abused by the militants).

As mentioned in the comments, Hamas itself may be considered a "charity" in some countries. In the Western world it is defined as a terrorist organization and cannot raise any funds. Any organization with direct links to it would also be disqualified once identified. That doesn't prevent them from trying and starting charities under various disguises which in reality launder money for the group. Those are usually [identified and shut down quickly](https://www.justice.gov/archive/opa/pr/2008/January/08_nsd_029.html), so if you're donating to an established charity with a track record of >20 years (or solid independent auditing and supervision on the ground), you're probably fine.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting information!. And will do...will stick to folks like Doctors without borders and Save the Childern. They have been out for over 20 years like you said.